# What are the optimal Intellitrace settings for an Azure hosted ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, intellitrace

I've got a very simple ASP.NET MVC-3 application that I'm trying to push to Azure for the first time.  Using Intellitrace, the default settings seem to take forever to pull the trace back down to the IDE.

I'm wondering if anyone knows the optimal Intellitrace settings to use to debug the initial application startup, which is still failing, without having to wait for so long to get the trace?

Comment: Setup RDP and remotely connect to the instance to see whats going on.  Be sure to checkout the eventlog.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the problem, the default settings should capture it.  They only time they wouldn't would be if the problem was outside of your code.  For instance if Azure had an issue with starting your instance.  But if the problem is in your OnStart or Startup scripts, IntelliTrace should capture it just fine by default.

Comment: The issues is that the default settings result in a huge capture, which takes forever to pull back from the server.  I'm looking for "optimal" settings, meaning a reduced configuration that would still capture most of the common startup issues (e.g. missing assemblies etc.).